# Make all form fields readonly in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am displaying 3 or more versions of a form.  One version is an edit form to edit all fields.  A second version will be a read only version of the same form which will be used to show all the same fields but with all fields having readonly="true" on the client side so that the user cannot enter data. The readonly fields need to use a different css style. This is to display archived data. I am already hiding the submit button so they can't submit but I want the form to look like it is readonly.  A third version will have some fields readonly and some editable for a particular class of users that has limited editing privileges.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0. How do I modify all (or a subset) of the fields displayed so they are readonly.  I would like to iterate through the collection of fields in the controller and set them all to readonly and also set the correct css class.  I don't want to have to put an if statement on every field in the .aspx file (there are 40-50 fields) and I'd prefer not to have this on client side so I can prevent users from modifying javascript/html to edit things they are not supposed to.

TIA,

Steve Shier

Comment: Just a side note: "so I can prevent users from modifying javascript/html to edit things they are not supposed to". Don't assume that just because you lock it in the html that a user cannot submit POST data back. It's very easy to fake a POST.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I use a partial view for form contents.  I'd like to treat the form as a collection of fields and chose the readonly fields based on external parameters (user's rights).  I want to re-use the same collection and set display properties based on the external paramaters.  I will have logic on the server side to make sure the user has the correct rights for an edit.  I would like to do this all server side and not use jquery.  If I use multiple partials, I have to copy and paste code and have a maintenance issue with a DRY violation.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 14):

Keep in mind that even if you set the tags as readonly on the server side, users can **still** change them through a variety of means, and whatever the value on the form is **before** it gets sent back to you.

Certainly the easiest way is client-side with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Or, you could do it in your View, but it's ugly. Off the top of my head, you would need some sort of `bool` passed into the View (via `ViewData` I suppose), and check that on *each* Input to see if you should add the `disabled` attribute. Not my idea of fun...

Comment: How would you add the disabled attribute on the server side?

Comment: @Steve - @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { disabled = "disabled" })

Answer (score 1):

I would have different views that correspond to your states and then choose the view depending on which state you are in.  You could also implement it with partials, breaking down the pieces so that you can easily include editable or read-only versions of the different sets of elements.  The read-only view, then, need not even include a form element.  You could also present the data in spans, divs, or paragraphs rather than as input elements.

Note: you'll still have to check whether the current user has the ability to update/create data in the actions that process form submits.  Just because you limit the ability to view data in a read-only format, that won't stop someone from crafting a form post to mimic your application if they want.  You can't rely on hiding/disabling things on the client to prevent a malicious user from trying to enter/modify data.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use partial views to represent forms and/or parts of forms.

I can think of two simple ways to do what you need (as I understood it):

1. `<% Html.RenderPartial(the_right_partial, model); %>` where `the_right_partial` is either a value passed from the controller or a helper (in which case, `the_right_partial(something)`);
2. pass a bool or enum paramether from controller representing editability and then using a helper to obtain the right htmlAttributes, like:
   `<%= Html.TextBox("name", value, Html.TheRightHtmlAttributesFor(isReadableOrNot)) %>`;

There may be other ways, like creating new helpers for input fields which accept an additional isReadableOrNot arg (but it seems an overkill to me), or like mangling the html/aspx in some odd (and totally unreadable/unmaintainable way), but I'd not suggest them.

Notice that using html attributes like `disabled` *is* client side, and with tools like firebug it takes just two seconds to change them.

Others have already said it, but I also have to: always assume that the user will do his/her best effort to do the worst possible thing, so check the user rights to modify stuff on server side, and consider client side checks as a courtesy to the user (to let her/him understand that the form is not supposed to be edited, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Since I am trying to use a single partial for the different states of the form, I am thinking I will create helper functions which will display correctly based on the state and the user.  The helpers will use a dictionary of fields that will indicate under which condition the field is read only.  I will still have server side checks to make sure data is valid and the user is authorized to make changes.

Thanks for all of your ideas and help.

Steve